# Is there such a construction as "to send hello" or "to send hi"?

Tags: greetings

Is there such a construction as "to send hello" or "to send hi"? 
Or something close? 
Or which is better?

Comment: No, whch means the third question is meaningless. On the second: Closer to what? But I think this question would fit better on [English Language Learners](/ell.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Sorry, misspelled - should have been 'close' in meaning to action when someone asks an another person to say to other people that he remembers them. In Russian it sounds like "say hi to [name] from me"

Comment: You can [**send** ***greetings***](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1AFAB_en___IT446&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#tbm=bks&q=send+greetings).

Comment: "Tell him/her I said hi"

Comment: Remember me to them! Send them my love!

Comment: You can say the same in English as Russian: "Say hello [or Hi] to *name* from me."

Comment: This doesn't seem much like a duplicate of the linked question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've stumbled upon such strucure several times: **Andrew sends his hello's** so looks like it could be used, even though to the majority of native English speakers it obviously doesn't sound normal. **Andrew gives/sends his regards** , probably, would be a better choice.

[Google Books results for "sends his hello"](https://www.google.ca/search?q=%22sends%20his%20hello%27s%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:de:official&client=firefox-a&channel=sb&gfe_rd=cr&ei=rk55VOy-M8iC8QeAoYCACg#rls=org.mozilla:de:official&channel=sb&tbm=bks&q=%22sends%20his%20hello%22)

Comment: Good call about the informal expression "[name/s] sends his/her/their hello's" It's the equivalent of *"sends his/her love"*. But I would not use it in the first person e.g. *I'm sending/I send my hello's* sounds almost arrogant and standoffish.

Comment: Ops, indeed. I am sorry about that. The link seems to be in order now.

Comment: 2 Mari-Lou:
"But I would not use it in the first person " - yes, indeed - that sounds weird, even though I believe I understand the origin of teh question as such construction does exist in different languages (Russian, for one - "Tell him I am sending (my) hello's to his brother".)

Comment: Yes, but it is the messenger who is delivering your "hello's" on your behalf.

Comment: Precisely so! So what is the conclusion? 
The construction could be used but as a part of reported speech only. Please correct me if I am worng.

Answer (score 0):

On Xmas cards, I often write "'Hi' to all!" (Verb implied - no need to sweat it.)

Answer (score 0):

"Say Hi to (name) from me" works fine in English too. Probably the most common way to say it.